# Azure Devops office Intergration 2019 Software error?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am unable to add the project in Excel using "Azure Devops Office Integration 2019" tool. Previously I worked many application using this software in excel with the same project which I am getting error now. Since, Last two weeks unable to see the projects when I add the ADO URL in the "Azure devops office server" . Could you please help me here why I am unable to get the team projects after adding the ADO url.

Note: For other Projects I am not getting any issue only for the particular project getting issue.

I am attaching the screenshot which will help to understand the issue.
[Azure devops office in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbrAi.png))

Thank you

I am unable get the team projects after adding the Azure devops URL.